# How to dump data from tables in clickhouse using mremoteNg?

Tags: nosql, data-warehouse, clickhouse

I use mRemoteNg to access my clickhouse db. I want to know how I dump table data/content from clickhouse in CSV format?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clickhouse-client](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/cli/) to download requred data to file:

```sh
clickhouse-client --host ch_server --user user_name --password user_password \
--query="SELECT * FROM db_name.table_name FORMAT CSVWithNames" \
> "/tmp/table_name_01.csv"
```

See available ouput formats by link [Formats for Input and Output Data](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#data-formatting)

Comment: Thanks @vladimir, I will try it and let you know